# MySQL Search Data Ignoring a word

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

Here i have this word "Basic Pediatric Echocardiography (Local)" 
but here in my db the data is "Basic Pediatric Echocardiography, 1 day (Local)"
so how i find the data although have word "1 day or 2 day" ?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL syntax `LIKE`

Comment: not working coz in my db the data is have word ", 1 day" or ", 2 day" sir

Comment: You have not made it very clear what you want to find and what you dont want to find. Can you add an example of what you want out of the query please

Comment: It would also be useful to see the code you currently have. As with almost all questions on SO if you show some code you will get much more help from the community, as we can see better what it is you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from tablename where word like 'Basic Pediatric Echocardiography,%(Local)'
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Answer (score 1):

use like operator

```
select * from table where col like '%Basic Pediatric Echocardiography%'
```

Comment: not working coz in my db the data is have word ", 1 day" or ", 2 day" sir

Comment: @RobyFirnando no problem 1 day 2 day if 1st pattern is correct like will return rows

Comment: word ", 1 day" and ", 2 day" in the middle sir so how ?

Comment: @RobyFirnando but in sample data you put 1day in last

Comment: Also note that the OP has a `codeigniter` tag on the question.

Comment: @RiggsFolly like is ansi sql it works for all supported db

Comment: try 'Basic Pediatric Echocardiography,%(Local)', see answer below

Answer (score 0):

Use like operator

```
select * from tablename
where word like '%Basic Pediatric Echocardiography%'
```

Comment: not working coz in my db the data is have word ", 1 day" or ", 2 day" sir

Comment: @RobyFirnando Did you bother to even test this query?  It should be working.

Comment: Also note that the OP has a `codeigniter` tag on the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Use **like operator** in your sql Query:-

```
"select * from tablename
 where word
 like '%Basic Pediatric Echocardiography%'";
```

For more Details , [please check](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)